# Google Cloud - App Engine site not loading

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine

I have deployed my application on Google Cloud Platform using App Engine, but I'm facing an issue where the site is not loading at all. It's not a matter of slow loading; the site simply does not load.

I have followed the necessary steps to deploy my application, including configuring the `app.yaml` file and deploying with the `gcloud app deploy` command. The deployment process completes without any errors, but when I try to access the site, it remains inaccessible.

Here are some details about my setup:

I am using a flexible environment for App Engine.
The application is built using Python and Flask.
I have verified that the necessary dependencies are included in the `requirements.txt` file.
I have confirmed that the main application file (`main.py`) and the `app.yaml` file are in the correct locations relative to each other.
I have checked the logs in the Google Cloud Platform console, and there are no error messages.
I have ran it locally and it runs just fine.

here is my app.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app


runtime_config:
  operating_system: ubuntu18
  runtime_version: 3.9


manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 50
```

I'm not sure what is causing the site to not load. I'm not sure if this is from Google Cloud or maybe Gunicorn.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: "...and there are no specific error messages related to my application..." Does that mean you see some errors but you don't think it has anything to do with your application?

Comment: No I meant there are no errors, sorry.

Comment: okay. When you ran it locally, did you run it with ```gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app```? If you didn't, run it that way and see if you get any errors

Comment: Hmm, ill try. I ran `flask run` and not that one.

Comment: I got this error:
   
 `from gunicorn.app.base import Application
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gunicorn\app\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from gunicorn import util
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gunicorn\util.py", line 8, in <module>
    import fcntl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'`

Comment: Do i need to change it to `flask run` in the app.yaml?

Comment: No. Flask isn't a production webserver. Are you running your App on Windows?

Comment: Yes, would you like to move this to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254243/discussion-between-nocommandline-and-pirogrammer).